# Post filtering by days is not working properly in the 10k tools

Tags: support, 10k-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Stats page on mod tools is broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103363/stats-page-on-mod-tools-is-broken)

The following two lists of questions look exactly the same to me, even though on the first one I've selected "30 days" and on the second one I've selected "today".

#### 30d:

[image]

#### today:

[image]

Is it only me?

Comment: It's not only you... They're the same posts displayed for all 5 date ranges, here *and*  on the main site.