# Stats page on mod tools is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

[Continuing in the vein of stuff I use that's been recently broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103305/messaged-users-anonymous-users), the `/tools?tab=stats` page no longer respects selected time periods. No matter which button I click and is highlighted, the page still shows the info for `today`.

For example, [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38083/less-harsh-word-than-stolen) was asked within the last `30d` and has a score of -7, yet [the lowest voted section on the stats page](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days) (10k on English only) only shows the posts from today, all of which have a higher score than -7.

(Another [example question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102183/why-are-editors-erasing-my-personality), this one here on MSO, also not appearing in [tools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=last30days)).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.  It was an encoding issue in the razor view that was rendering `&amp;daterange=` in the querystring on the AJAX calls rather than `&daterange=`, so everything was falling back to the "2 days" default.